# hide user list on ubuntu trusty login?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I'd like to hide the user list on my Ubuntu Trusty login page.

[This page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) tells me that I should set up a configuration in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d, and call it whatever I want.  This does not work, and the page has a disconcerting message saying that Ubuntu is no longer testing LightDM.  (But according to /etc/X11/default-display-manager, I'm using /usr/sbin/lightdm.)

[This page](http://www.tejasbarot.com/2014/04/24/hide-disable-guest-remote-login-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr/#axzz348yQjO1v) tells me to create a configuration in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf, which also does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer from Jun 10 at 15:42 has a typo:
you need to insert greeter-hide-users=true (not "false")

The following config worked for me:

[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
greeter-hide-users=true
greeter-show-manual-login=true

Answer (score 0):

looks like the correct place to change it is in /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d

I edited 50-ubuntu.conf and put my settings in there.  (If you set greeter-hide-users=false, make sure you set greeter-show-manual-login=true !)

Once you have done it, run "sudo restart lightdm" to restart Ubuntu.